# Open navigation drawer by clicking the app icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to let my user open the navigation drawer by clicking the app icon. This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.

    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
           R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
            ) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_activity_add);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_title);
        }
    };


    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // Pressing the app icon in the action bar will navigate to the parent activity.
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}
```

But when I tap the icon, nothing happens. Where is the problem.

Answer (score 22):

Have a look here for an [example of the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon). You need additional code in

- `onPostCreate()` to sync your Drawer state
- **`onOptionsItemSelected()` to handle the touch event of the App icon**
- `onConfigurationChanged()` to provide the new configuration to the drawer

  ```
  public class YourActivity extends Activity {

  public ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
      mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle();
      ...
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
       mDrawerToggle.syncState();
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
       // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
       if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
           return true;
       }
       // Handle your other action bar items...

       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you. When I add this code, it says that mDrawerToogle can't be resolved. I tried making it like this: "public ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle" but it didn't help. I'm not very experienced concerning java.

Comment: @user2971688 Have the ActionBarDrawerToggle as a field in your Activity and change the code parts like in onCreate accordingly.

Comment: I added

your onPostCreate(), onConfigurationChanged and your onOptionsItemSelected, but it says "mDrawerToggle cannot be resolved"?

Comment: @user2971688 Look closely to the onCreate and the line above.

Comment: There is no constructor for ActionBarDrawerToogle as explained above

The correct constructor is:
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(activity, drawerLayout, drawerImageRes, openDrawerContentDescRes, closeDrawerContentDescRes)

Answer (score 17):

You should override `onOptionsItemSelected` of the activity and use this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```